# How to make ajax request work on page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an ajax request that updates a piece of text on the screen when a dropdown input is selected using 'onchange'. However i want the same behaviour to happen on page load as well but i cant seem to find the correct syntax.

```html
    $(document).on('change','#standalone-invoice-billpayer', function (evt) {
       updateCardDetailsText(evt)
    });
```

So above, i click on the dropdown called 'standalone-invoice-billpayer' and then execute the function which contains the ajax request which works perfectly. But i want the same thing for on page load. I am using Ruby on Rails. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Turbolinks you will need to add an event listener for the `turbolinks:load` event. If you just add a listener for the `jQuery.ready` event it will only be fired once on the initial page load and not when the page is replaced by turbolinks.

> Turbolinks triggers a series of events during navigation. The most
>   significant of these is the turbolinks:load event, which fires once on
>   the initial page load, and again after every Turbolinks visit.
>   - https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(evt) {
  updateCardDetailsText(evt);
});
```

If you are not using turbolinks you can just fire it with `jQuery.ready`:

```
// shorthand for jQuery.ready(function(){ ... });
$(function(){
  updateCardDetailsText(evt);
});
```

You can also just fire the ajax call as soon as the script is loaded and then modify the DOM as soon as its ready to be manipulated:

```
jQuery.getJSON('/foo.json').done(function(data){
  $(function(){
    modify_the_dom_with(data);
  });
});
```

This can be an important optimization if you have elements that are populated via ajax as they will appear to be much snappier.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the change event on the element in the code:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change','#standalone-invoice-billpayer', function (evt) {
       updateCardDetailsText(evt)
    });
    $("#standalone-invoice-billpayer").change();
});
```

The call to `.change()` will cause the event handler to run, and it will then call `updateCardDetailsText()`.

Comment: i dont quite understand. I trying to find out how to make the 'updateCardDetailsText(evt)' function run on a page load.

Comment: @b.herring that is what that code does... as long as `standalone-invoice-billpayer` exists at that time

Comment: Calling `change` on the element will trigger any other event handlers bound to the element and may cause other side effects like the browser scrolling down to the element.

Answer (score -1):

proper triggering is like this, however the evt value will just get whatever default value you have in the element "#standalone-invoice-billpayer"

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load",function() {

 $("#standalone-invoice-billpayer").trigger('change');

});
```